# Shift + F not working in Outlook and Word only

Tags: microsoft-office, shortcuts

Get an annoying problem here. The Shift + F doesn't produce a capital F, but only in Word 365 and Outlook 365 ( in Outlook, it produce the capital F in the adress bar but not in the message section )

Using a Surface Pro 4, tested with a Microsoft wired keyboard AND the Surface flap keyboard, nothing can solve this trouble.

Caps Lock still give me the capital F. Did a reset shortcut in Options - Ribbon - keyboard but nothing more.

The fact that this combinaison worked everywhere else, even Excel and Teams ( as I was suspecting Office 365 suite ) worked fine.

Please help ?!

Comment: What is it producing then ? Just a normal lower case f ? Also, make sure this isnt something that got into your Autocorrect settings from word.

Comment: On a Word document or in the message field in Outlook, it goes backward if other letters only on the last 3 characters and the pointer goes back where it was. It's maybe not clear but it acted like the left arrow, only ont the first three characters before, if there was. If no others letter, nothing happen, not even a f...

Comment: On the autocorrect, how can I see if it is not allowing? a capital F with the Shift button? Remember that with the Caps Lock it's working fine, also anywhere else in the computer...

Comment: Also, I did try it on the web based app of Outlook and Word and it works. I did try to repair, re-install the app, no change. I'm really stuck with that weird problem.

Comment: It is indeed very weird. You can find autocorrect under File->Options->Proofing. There is a button Autocorrect Options there. However its very unlikely thats the problem, because it would replace any "F" and wouldnt be able to replace it with "left arrow" like behaviour. Things you could try: Turn off proofing, turn off add-ins and disable all macros.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work :( In fact, only one add-in is Phish Alert and can't be removed or disabled as an internal policy. Obviously, this is not the problem anyway.

Comment: Just trying to think with you what it could be. The connection between Outlook and Word is simply because Outlook uses Word as its editor and as such borrows any setting that comes with it. Those are the only 2 Office apps that are tied in that way. I'm out of ideas what might be causing it though :(

Comment: Have you tried starting word in safe mode ? You can do this by holding the ctrl key while starting word, or by pressing win+r and in the run box typing "winword /safe"

Comment: Yep, still no solution with that... and only the F character... that is intelligible... and that it's giving the ''left arrow'' move three times and cursor goes back where it was. It's not even a function in MS Word